# Regex: Search particular diacritics and replace it in particular tag with ASCII (notepad++)

Tags: regex, windows-10, notepad++

I have many html lines with words that contains `ă` diacritic such as:  `creatăoare, singură, acasă`, etc. from the tag `<p class="text_obisnuit"></p>`

I want to find all those `ă` diacritics from that tag, ant to replace it in ASCII with `&#259;`

I made a regex, but the "replace" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Search:

`(?-s)(\G(?!^)|<p\s+class="text_obisnuit">)((?!</p>).)*?\K[ă]`

Replace by:

`&#259;`

Comment: Add info to question not into answer section

Comment: Feel free to remove the final character set - just match plain `ă` at the end, a character set is for when you need to match one of many possible characters :)

Comment: Question and answer at the same second! `07:08:38Z`. And you do such thing for approx all your questions, why?

Comment: hello, I don't work here, I just find a solution and share it, maybe someone need help. I don't want any credits.